# Implementing Scilab FIR filter in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scilab

I am using the guide below:

http://www.neurotraces.com/scilab/scilab2/node50.html

And I am having particular difficulty with this line:

```
hz = horner (hpoly, (1/%z))
```

Is there a way to evaluate polynomials using rational function arguments in numpy?

Edit: The code above was taken from the link. It's in scilab.

```
valcoeff = wfir ('lp', 4, [.2 0], 'hm', [0 0]) 
hpoly =  poly (valcoeff, 'z','coeff')
hz = horner (hpoly, (1/%z))
lisys = syslin ('d', hz)
```

This is my attempt, so far, to port it in python:

```
valcoeff    = signal.firwin( 130, [1./128, 64./128], pass_zero=False )
hpoly       = numpy.poly1d( valcoeff, variable= 'z' )
```

Comment: What code have you attempted that led up to your trouble?

Comment: Can you show some output ?

Comment: Can you post what you have done before the `horner` line. I think you don't need the `horner` function.

Comment: After browsing over your scilab code link, I didn't notice anything special about that FIR design, except extra manual steps. You might want to consider the example http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/FIRFilter . Also reading a bit about windowing functions helps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function